# Cloud Run connect to a self hosted MySql instance with Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I tried to connect to my MySql instance from cloud run, but when i deploy to cloud run the ip of the database is always replaced.

My connection string:

DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:test@202.x.x.x:3306/my_db?serverVersion=8.0"

Then if try to deploy it says:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'35.x.x.x' (using password: YES)

It looks like this IP 35.x.x.x is a google cloud IP, but where does this IP come from??? And when I deploy again there is another google IP.

Comment: How are you connecting? Normally, only the hostname or IP are used in connection string. You can't connect through LAN IP or localhost? Some more details about DB and web server might help question (e.g. in different datacenters, all on 1 machine, on same LAN, etc.)

Comment: If i tried this locally it worked, so i can connect to my external MySql instance. So it looks like thiis is a CloudRun problem. The server structure looks like this. Google CloudRun Container -> Self hosted vServer with MySql (None Google Cloud Server).

Comment: That's strange, I deployed a Symfony app on Cloud Run last week, using a Cloud SQL and I didn't had any issues like that... And I don't think Cloud Run would change anything by itseft. Maybe share with us some more info (build, docker, ...)

Comment: Cloudrun SQL is working. But iam talking about a self hosted MySQL instance.

Comment: Can you share how do you connect to your database in your code?

Answer (score 1):

> It looks like this IP 35.x.x.x is a google cloud IP, but where does
> this IP come from???

Google Cloud Run is a managed serverless container service. The containers run behind a GFE (Google FrontEnd) which provides authorization, proxying, and load balancing. The IP address is the address of the Google frontend in front of your container.

> And when I deploy again there is another google IP.

This is expected. The infrastructure for Cloud Run supports thousands/millions of services. Deployments do not necessarily run on the exact same hardware. Expect the IP address to change at any time.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'35.x.x.x' (using
> password: YES)

This error is reported by your database. A secure solution for you is complex. To allow access you must `GRANT` privileges to the user at the database. If you use wildcards for the user's IP address, this is not a best practice. I am also assuming that you are not using TLS connections, which means the username and password are sent in the clear over the Internet.

**Recommendation**

When deploying services with Google Cloud Run, I do not recommend self-hosted databases. This is one area where Cloud Run's integration with Cloud SQL solves numerous integration and security issues.

If you must use a self-hosted database, you have limited options:

- GRANT the user access from any IP address. This is not a good idea. Implement encrypted connections. Do not allow `root` access from the world. Create a dedicated user and rotate the password on a scheduled basis.
- Implement a proxy to create a secure encrypted connection from Cloud Run to the instance running your database. The proxy runs in the same VPC as the database. The instance running the database does not have a public IP address, only a private IP address.
- Setup a static outbound IP address. This uses a VPC connector that routes traffic from Cloud Run thru your project's VPC Cloud NAT instance. See the link below for more information. Note: this method can also support direct access to the database private IP address.

[Access Control and Account Management](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/8.0/en/access-control.html)

[MySQL GRANT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html)

[Configuring MySQL to Use Encrypted Connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-encrypted-connections.html)

[Cloud Run Static outbound IP address](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip)